# Is there any way to trace a pdf?

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to trace when/where/by whom a pdf that I own is opened? I can modify it and send it as need be.

I was thinking of something like a script that is attached to the pdf, but that would be a separate file that one could easily remove. If this is not the correct path of thinking, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most pdf viewer programs don't execute the contained JavaScript.

Comment: You can't rely on scripts. You need to encrypt the file in such a way that a server is required to decrypt it. The server can then track the decryptions. Adobe has a solution but it's quite expensive. But look at FileOpen.https://www.fileopen.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your pdf file into an executable format. When user run this executable - it will extract the pdf from resources and runs a process with a pdf viewer and logs opening time.